# Angular-UI-router resolve not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I got this problem where when i use resolve in Angular-ui-router causes my site to do hundreds of get requests per second but not load the view. I am using the full MEAN-stack.

The views are created with inline templates e.g:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">......</script>
```

And then used in a `<ui-view>` tag.

Please look at this code:

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    o.getAll = function() {
      return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
        angular.copy(data, o.posts);
      });
    };
    return o;
}]);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',

    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve : {
                postPromise : ['posts',
                function(posts) {
                    return posts.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })
```

If i dont use the Resolve, the page is fine, it loads.

EDIT:
I have boiled it down to that the code i wrote was for angular  version <= 1.4 and therefore i need to use .then instead of .success, but when i use .then i dont get the persistent data that the factory is supposed to do.

So new question, should i just stay on angularJs 1.4 or try/get help to convert this to 1.6? Appreciate all the answers, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly returning `$http` `promise` object,  take `promise` object into a variable and return it. Please do as fallows, it worked for me.

```
 var promise = $http.get('posts');
     promise.then(function(response) {

            },
        function(data) {

            });
 return promise;
```

Please note `success` and `error` call backs are deprecated in `angular 1.6`, use `then`.

1. [Documentation](http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2016/12/angular-160-released.html)
2. [Other resource](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-6-is-here)